# Laravel Eloquent - sync() on a Morph relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

It seems like there is no `sync()` function for morph tables on Laravel.

I have two tables `avails` and `questions`. `questions` is a `morphMany` table. I want to use the sync command, and this is what I did:

```
Avail::find($id)->questions()->sync($some_ids);
```

This gives me the following error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sync()

So is there a way to get `sync` to work or am I just not doing this right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`morphMany` is a 1-to-many, not many-to-many relation, so there is no `sync` method.

Use `saveMany`/`save` instead, and `associate` for the other way around.

---

to mimic `sync` behaviour for this kind of relation you can do this:

```
$questionsOld = $avail->questions()->get();

$questionsOld->each(function ($question) {
  // appropriate fields here:
  // 1*
  $question->FOREIGN_ID = null;
  $question->FOREIGN_TYPE = null;
  $question->save();
});

$questionsNew = Question::whereIn('id', $someIds)->get();

// *2
$avail->questions()->saveMany($questionsNew->getDictionary());
```

Now:

*1 you can't use `dissociate` and must explicitly set `relation_id` and `relation_type` to null, since `morphTo` doesn't override this method, so it wouldn't work as expected.

*2 `getDictionary()` returns simple array of models, instead of collection. It's required becase `saveMany` typehints its parameter as `array`.

Comment: Makes sense. So I have a list of `questions`. When I update them, I want to basically sync the question ids. There may be new questions, removed questions, or simply updated questions. How would I go about syncing them without sync? I could just get the list of ids, and compare them with the old ids and then manually remove/add/update